# Dyson Schwinger equations for quantum electrodynamics on small scales

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-gravity

Considering the Quantum electrodynamics connected partition function $W[J] = -i\ln Z[J]$ with

$Z = \int D[A_\mu] \int D[\psi^\dagger] \int D[\psi]exp(i \int_\Omega d^4x (-i\psi^\dagger \gamma_\mu(\partial^\mu + ieA^\mu)\psi + \frac{1}{2}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu \nu})+J_\mu A^\mu +J_\psi \psi + J_{\psi^\dagger} \psi^\dagger)$.

Then, it follows from the invariance of the partition function under shifts in variables and after some calculations (I choose the gauge $\partial_\mu A^\mu = 0$) a hierarchy of equations, where for $J=0$ I will obtain the Euler-Lagrange equations averaged with path integral and for derivatives of $W[J]$ by $J$ evaluated at $J=0$ I get all other Dyson-Schwinger equations. These will be differential equations for ($<>$ denotes path integral averaging) $<\psi>,<\psi^\dagger>,<A_\mu>$ and all (higher-order) deviations that may be very difficult (system of nonlinear equations). Even a supercomputer can solve the Dyson-Schwinger equations only for not so large powers of fields. To simplify this, I have to make some assumptions. The region $\Omega$ is bounded and is on small scales (around 1 femtometer). Therefore, quantum uncertainty effects become more significant.

Can I neglect all cubic terms like $\frac{\delta^3W[J]}{\delta J_\mu \delta J_\psi \delta J_{\psi^\dagger}}$ when I assume that quadradic deviations (variances and covariances) are significantly smaller than $<\psi>,<\psi^\dagger>,<A_\mu>$? Do I need the higher order deviations on small scales? When higher order deviations have significant contributions to the system?

I would also say that on very high interaction potentials I need higher order deviations.

Another question (that is not a must to answer it in the answer, one can answer this question optional): Can I do a Dyson-Schwinger equation approach for General Relativity with Einstein-Hilbert action? I know that General Relativity is perturbatively nonrenormizable, but can I make real quantum gravity by nonperturbative Dyson-Schwinger equations?

Comment: About Quantum Gravity: a nonperturbative path integral for QG is an old idea. The problem with this though is that no satisfactory nonperturbative precise in the mathematical sense definition of $\left< \dots \right>$ has been given to this integral yet, except for spinfoam models which are, I believe, still under active investigation.